# Android, accessing to database via fragments throws "exception in initializer error"?

Tags: android, database, exception

In my activity, I have 4 fragments. One of them needs to connect to Database and get its data. However, when I run my application error happens and logcat shows:

```
07-19 02:09:01.011: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-19 02:09:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-19 02:09:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  at com.astro.database.DatabaseHandler.<init>(DatabaseHandler.java:26)
07-19 02:09:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  at com.astro.fragments.TopRecipesFragment.onActivityCreated(TopRecipesFragment.java:96)
07-19 02:09:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:892)
07-19 02:09:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
07-19 02:09:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(229):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
.
.
.
```

Code of my Fragment is like this:

```
public class TopRecipesFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_toprecipes, container, false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "View created.");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "inside onActivityCreated()");

        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);

    }

    .
    .
    .

}
```

Then, DatabaseHandler class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); // Error happens here
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

and finally, DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";   
    private static final String COLUMN_ID     = "_id";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have no idea why it happens. Any suggestion(s) would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Where does the `context` field in your fragment come from? My guess is that is probably `null` and this is causing the exception. Try using `dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity())`. (an activity is, naturally, a `Context`)

Comment: Thanks dear Nikolay, Actually I'm suspicious to context as well. I tested your suggestion, however response was same. same crash happened. Thanks

Comment: above, dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);, I put a toast message and it works. Therefore, this context for toast doesn't have problem but it is not acceptable for database!

Comment: Interesting. Can you instantiate `DatabaseHelper` from an activity without errors?

Comment: ohhhh, I have put DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this); in an activity and FragmentActivity but I had same error. :(